# Probelmas en angular con suscribe

Tags: angular

Hola colegas tengo un problema osea no al copilar ya que si copila pero mi problema es que primero me ejecuta el alert y la condiciones y luego el subscribe por que se da eso me podrian ayudar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es tema de asíncronia, coloca desde el alert hasta el fin del elde donde dice SIII, dentro del subscribe.

Comment: No olvides que cuando ejecutas un servicio que va al servidor éste se ejecuta en segundo plano, lo que tienes allí es simple: primero ejecuta el servicio **getPeliculas** (OJO que no sabes cuanto va a demorar), posteriormente ejecuta `alert(this.peliculas.length);` cuando en realidad el servicio talvez ni siquiera volvió del servidor por lo mismo **`peliculas.length`** podría tener un valor de 0, ese **if** y ese **else** que tienes deberían estar al momento en el que el valor retorna del servidor en este caso en lugar de `alert(data);` como bien te menciona el usuario *Isanchezo*. ;)

Comment: Te sugiero que cuando formules añadas el paso a paso de la ejecución que te responde y que esperas, si puedes no pegues la foto copia y pega el Código ayuda a responder mas rápido y se sugiere por el sitio evitar el uso de imágenes si es posible

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas trabajando con asincronía y esto funciona así:

1. ejecutas la petición y ella se coloca en el stack de ejecución
2. ejecutas las condiciones, donde supongo te responde **"SIIII"** en un alert y acaba la ejecución.

Ahora para solucionarlo es simple si tienes que esperar a que la petición se complete para lo otro solo tienes que pasar las condiciones dentro de el callback que tienes en el suscribe así

```
this.service.getPeliculas()
    .suscribe(peliculas =>{

        alert(this.peliculas.length);
        if(this.peliculas.length === 0)
            this.verifivarPelicula();
        else
            alert('SIII')

    });
```

En otros casos puedes user async y await para hacer que espere la petición en casos en los que lo que vas a acer sea un modulo aparte y no en misma petición, pero para este caso eso debe bastar.

te dejo por aca documentos anexos del tema:

- [promesas](https://docs.angular.lat/guide/observables-in-angular)
- [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)